# Spring batch how to fail a step and therefor the job from inside a Partitioner

Tags: java, spring-batch

I currently have a partitioner extending partitiner and Overriding the method partition.

In the partition method I try to read configuration records from the database in order to partition downloads

If I'm unable to read from the database for some reason I want to fail the Job.

How do I do exactly that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleJobOperator` bean for this purpose.

`SimpleJobOperator` bean has method `jobOperator.stop(executionId)` method which takes `executionId` of job as parameter.

You can get `executionId` from `JobExecution`. 
    something like this `executionId =JobExecution.getId();`

I am using similar setup and it's working fine. Hope this helps

Comment: Nice one! Thank you!

Comment: If the solution helped you Could you please accept the answer ? This will also help who are facing similar issues and will help both of us to gain some reputation :)

Comment: I havent used your solution I went with the solution I wrote about below I have no idea if eather is the correct one at hte moment havent had time to werify pros and cons. so for now Im waiting for a second opinion or other clues on what to do. will get back to this thread if I ever get the posibility to verify eather ansver. But since I do not know I'm not going to take a guess,

Comment: Finally had time to look into this again, Nirajs answer is correct thank you Niraj!